# Variance of the prediction of a two-point change after linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression, prediction

This may be an absolutely basic question, so forgive me if it is.

Let's say I have the following regression output

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = fake)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9434 -0.6851  0.0231  0.6744  3.6313 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.130431   0.056489  -2.309   0.0211 *  
x1           0.014597   0.003454   4.226 2.59e-05 ***
x2          -0.025518   0.062429  -0.409   0.6828    
---
```

Now, I want to predict *y* from new data. I'm specifically interested in the *error* around my prediction.

Let's say that one row in the new observed dataset has

```
x1 = 2
x2 = 0
```

The expected value for `y_pred` is

```
y_pred = -0.1304 + 2 * 0.01460
```

...but what is the standard deviation of that prediction? Can I figure out 95% CIs on that prediction?

And specifically, would I figure those out by applying the std. error of `beta_1` twice, once for each unit increase, or do I apply it only once?

EDIT to add: I don't have the original data, just the coefficient estimate and SE...so calculating using matrix algebra won't be possible.

Comment: The question doesnt really make sense. You cant have a standard deviation (or CI) of a single point value...

Comment: That's....not at all true. You absolutely can get a prediction interval around a prediction.